# What does empty href for html <base> tag means?

Tags: html, angular, base-tag

Suppose my page URL is: `http://example.com/path/to/dir/index.html`

And I proxy this page via: `http://proxyserver.com/path/to/dir/index.html`.
Similarly I want all relative URLs in page to be resolved by `proxyserver.com` instead of `example.com`. What should be the proper `<base>` href value?

I want relative URLs on page like

- `newfile.html` to resolve to `http://proxyserver.com/path/to/dir/newfile.html`
- `/newfile.html` to resolve to `http://proxyserver.com/newfile.html`
- `#hash` to resolve to `http://proxyserver.com/path/to/dir/file.html#hash`

Setting `<base href="" />` in page does the job correctly but does it have some implication? Does it have different interpretation across browsers? What does empty `href` value actually mean? Will it work for all frameworks like angular?

I have heard that `<base>` tag is mandatory for angular apps to initialize and hence removing `<base>` tag might not work.

**NOTE: The website may already contain some `<base>` tag which I would always like to override.**

I also tried `<base href="/" />` but it will resolve relative URLs

- `newfile.html` to `http://proxyserver.com/newfile.html`
  and
- `#hash` to `http://proxyserver.com/#hash`
  which is wrong.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it is how base works, i don't get the problem

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I cannot find any documentation which tells what does empty value of `href` mean for `<base>` tag. Is it same as not setting it or removing existing `<base>` tag? But then Angular Apps where `<base>` is mandatory would break.

Comment: Empty means the root like every tchonology

Answer (score 0):

A base URL, or base location, is the unique root URL with which relative URLs can be converted into absolute URLs for a website. Multiple bases are impossible.

More complex, inconsistent policies can be enforced with redirection rules. This duty belongs to the web server. To list few, NginX, Apache and IIS all have the ability to set redirection rules. There you can do whatever you like with regular expressions.

Since this question is tagged Angular, then, since client-wise a page is accessed only after the web server resolves an http request, you would have to create a blank page redirecting to the correct page for every wrong case. Which is of course worse than letting the web server handle redirections.

Answer (score 0):

`<base href="" />` defines the base for all relative paths.
And it obey´s the Highlander principle ("THERE CAN ONLY BE ONE") :-)

Just to check if i understand your aim right. You wrote:

- `newfile.html` to resolve to `http://proxyserver.com/path/to/dir/newfile.html`
- `/newfile.html` to resolve to `http://proxyserver.com/newfile.html`

So you do NOT want to have ONE Basepath, but you want that the browser checks multiple paths if there is the document you need?

This is not easily possible (from the Browser perspective). The reason is, that the browser does not know the content of those paths. He has to create requests to those server(s) "Hey nice server, do you have a "newfile.html" in your directory? No? Okay thank you."

Like @Attersson said, if you want to achieve that, you have to create filters and routings in your webserver. That would be no job for the client.

Now about Angular.
In Angular 6, you would write `<base href="/">` in your index.html.
AND THEN configure in the `Angular.json` the base path you really want:

```
...
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
             ...
            "baseHref": "/myLovedPath/",
...
```

as a result, Angular will build the application and change `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/myLovedPath/">`

warm regards

Comment: what if in Angular, I write `<base href="">` i.e. empty `href` value? Will it break?

Comment: @lazyvab you have to use redirections in your web server. This is not meant to be handled client sided (Angular). Anyway empty base means current host.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.
There can be at maximum one  element in a document, and it must be inside the  element.

if you domine like `http://proxyserver.com` the base url will be / , but if the domine 
like this `http://proxyserver.com/appname/` so the base url will be like **/appname/** and you normaly will set the base url during the deploy with angular cli like this

```
ng build --prod --bh=/appname/
```

In this case you have to use `**HashLocationStrategy**` for routes

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule  
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } 
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

> { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }